# Can I move some npm dependencies into another project and then to install that project as a dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm

I try to move some dependencies from a project to another project in order to have a cleaner view in my package json regarding the project I work on. Most of dependencies I mention are build dependencies, so they are somehow poluting my actual project. I prepared the sub-project with only a `package.json` containing those build packages as devDependencies, and I published to npm, then I installed that package as a devDependency into my project. So far, so good... except npm does not install the packages contained by the sub-project.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I just had to set packages in sub project as dependencies, not devDependencies.